# In Javascript, why does the constructor property point to the base-most constructor in the prototype chain?

Tags: javascript

I'm curious about this design of Javascript, and perhaps any reasons for this architecture or design patterns that can be employed to take advantage of this.

The `constructor` property of an object is always a reference to the function that created that object, correct?

However, take this code:

```
  function base()
  {
     this.SayHi = function ()
     {
        window.alert('Hi');
     };
  }

  function subclass()
  {
     this.SayBye = function ()
     {
        window.alert('Bye');
     };
  }

  subclass.prototype = new base();

  var s = new subclass();
  s.SayHi();
  s.SayBye();
  window.alert(s.constructor);
```

The last line will echo the constructor for `base`, even though we know `subclass` was called to create the object (otherwise `SayBye` would not work).

One potential work-around would be to simply do:

```
subclass.prototype.constructor = subclass;
```

Perhaps a more concise way of asking my question is why is `s.constructor` equal to `subclass.prototype.constructor` and not `subclass.constructor`, since `s` is an instanceof subclass.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> All objects inherit a `constructor` property from their **prototype**.

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor#Description).

That's just how it works. You often do see people [explicitly setting the `constructor` property](http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#object.prototype) to something that seems more intuitive to them.

Comment: +1 for the Javascript Garden link, that was an interesting read!  Resolved a few misconceptions I've had for years.

Comment: That statement is confusing as it can easily be construed to mean the object's public prototype, whereas inheritance is from *internal* proptotypes. Another edit to MDN required.

Comment: @RobG: Thanks, I'll reflect the new text (when you change it).

Comment: Sounds like the answer to my question is "It works this way because that's how it's supposed to work" :)